# Compare two dataframe, one has time range and the other one has specific time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrame. df1 is driving record with 2 columns(drinvg start/end).
df2 is car accident record with accident time. What I want to do is get CAR_NUMBER from df2 and search in df1. When the CAR_NUMBER found in df1, check if the ACCD_TIME is between START_TIME and END_TIME. If no, move to next row. If yes, make ACCD_TIME column and write down the ACCD_TIME like output. Please help.

df1

```
START_TIME          END_TIME      CAR_NUMBER
2019-01-01 8:01   2019-01-01 9:00   A12345
2019-01-02 11:30  2019-01-02 13:00  A12345
2019-01-03 9:30   2019-01-03 10:00  A12345
2019-01-01 9:30   2019-01-01 10:30  B23456
2019-01-02 9:00   2019-01-02 9:17   B23456
2019-01-04 13:00  2019-01-04 14:50  B23456
2019-02-01 16:00  2019-02-01 17:00  C34567
2019-02-05 8:14   2019-02-05 8:30   C34567
2019-02-06 11:00  2019-02-06 11:20  C34567
```

df2

```
ACCD_TIME         CAR_NUMBER
2019-01-02 12:00    A12345
2019-02-06 11:10    C34567
```

output

```
START_TIME          END_TIME      CAR_NUMBER   ACCD_TIME
2019-01-01 8:01   2019-01-01 9:00   A12345        NULL
2019-01-02 11:30  2019-01-02 13:00  A12345    2019-01-02 12:00
2019-01-03 9:30   2019-01-03 10:00  A12345        NULL
2019-01-01 9:30   2019-01-01 10:30  B23456        NULL
2019-01-02 9:00   2019-01-02 9:17   B23456        NULL
2019-01-04 13:00  2019-01-04 14:50  B23456        NULL
2019-02-01 16:00  2019-02-01 17:00  C34567        NULL
2019-02-05 8:14   2019-02-05 8:30   C34567        NULL
2019-02-06 11:00  2019-02-06 11:20  C34567    2019-02-06 11:10
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `pandas.DataFrame.merge` and then `pandas.Series.between` and `where`:

```
new_df = df.merge(df2, how='outer', left_on="CAR_NUMBER", right_on="CAR_NUMBER")
new_df['ACCD_TIME'] = new_df['ACCD_TIME'].where(new_df['ACCD_TIME'].between(new_df['START_TIME'], new_df['END_TIME']))
```

Output:

```
           START_TIME            END_TIME CAR_NUMBER           ACCD_TIME
0 2019-01-01 08:01:00 2019-01-01 09:00:00     A12345                 NaT
1 2019-01-02 11:30:00 2019-01-02 13:00:00     A12345 2019-01-02 12:00:00
2 2019-01-03 09:30:00 2019-01-03 10:00:00     A12345                 NaT
3 2019-01-01 09:30:00 2019-01-01 10:30:00     B23456                 NaT
4 2019-01-02 09:00:00 2019-01-02 09:17:00     B23456                 NaT
5 2019-01-04 13:00:00 2019-01-04 14:50:00     B23456                 NaT
6 2019-02-01 16:00:00 2019-02-01 17:00:00     C34567                 NaT
7 2019-02-05 08:14:00 2019-02-05 08:30:00     C34567                 NaT
8 2019-02-06 11:00:00 2019-02-06 11:20:00     C34567 2019-02-06 11:10:00
```